# How to show error message like "Duplicate Category not permitted" if category already exist

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I had a dropdown with categories. when i select a particular category second time it has to show error message like "Duplicate Category not permitted" in V-Rules.

Below is my code.

```js
     checkForDuplicateCategory(){
      let newEstimates = this.newEstimates.map((estimate) => {
        return estimate.category?.toLowerCase();
      });
      if (newEstimates.includes(this.bid.category?.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

category rules

   

      categoryRules: [
        v => !!v && !/^\s+$/.test(v) || "Invoice type is required",
            v => { this.checkForDuplicateCategory() }
      ]
```

How to show error message when user try to add same category second time.

Comment: Are you asking how to conditionally show or hide an html element containing the error message?

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of returning true or false, set an error property in your component.
- Conditionaly show an alert in the ui when the property is set.
- Clear the error when the user clicks the alert.